# Interface setData not working on newly added columns

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5, interface, saving

So I created a custom module that extends a second module. I added a db schema to the new module from the table of the second module. When I try to use the interface, the setData('oldColumns', value) are working but not setData('newColumns', value).